# package ‘arulesSequences’ installation in R

Tags: r

Very simple problem I haven't been able to solve. How do I install this package? This is what I get, which is the typical message you get when something doesn't exist in the CRAN repository. But I see its existence here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/arulesSequences/index.html

```
install.packages('arulesSequences')
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/harof/Documents/R/win-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘arulesSequences’ is not available (for R version 3.2.1)
```

Comment: try updating your R version to 3.2.2

Comment: @erasmortg thanks you deserve 1000 points